# cellForItemAtIndexPath not called with custom UICollectionViewLayout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

This is how I initialize the collectionView:

```
self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame collectionViewLayout:[[customLayout alloc]init]];
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
//[self.collectionView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];
[self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
UINib *nibf = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"inviteUserCell" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:nibf forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"user"];
[self addSubview:self.collectionView];
```

Than I have the following Delegate Methods:

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
     NSLog(@"sections 1");
     return 1;
 }
 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     NSLog(@"items 40");
     return 40;
 }
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     inviteUserCell *cell = (inviteUserCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"user" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
     NSLog(@"CELL: %@", cell);
     return cell;
 }
```

In my log I get `sections 1` and `items 40` but I do not get `CELL: %@`. For my subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` I have the following methods.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds{
     return true;
 }
 - (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize{
     CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.frame.size.height);
     return size;
 }
 - (NSArray<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect{
     NSArray *attributesInRect = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
     for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *cellAttributes in attributesInRect) {
        // [self modifyLayoutAttributes:cellAttributes];
          cellAttributes.size = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
          cellAttributes.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
     }
     return attributesInRect;
 }
 - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // [self modifyLayoutAttributes:attributes]; 
      attributes.size = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
      attributes.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
     NSLog(@"Attr: %@", attributes);    // this is null
     return attributes;
 }
```

I'm not sure what I'm not calling or setting that would get `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to be called.

**Layout**
Desired layout is a 50x50 grid with vertical & horizontal scrolling. From reading around `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is only capable of vertical or horizontal scrolling. So I subclassed `UICollectionViewLayout`

Comment: Are you subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` or `UICollectionViewLayout`?

Comment: "Desired layout is a 50x50 grid with vertical & horizontal scrolling. From reading around `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is only capable of vertical or horizontal scrolling. So I subclassed `UICollectionViewLayout`." ... Yes, that is correct. You'll want to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

A few observations:

1. The key issue is that `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` should be returning an array of layout attributes for all of the cells visible in a particular rect. If you don't return an array of attributes objects, one for each visible cell, it won't ask `cellForItemAt` to generate any cells.

   Now, how you will do this for your particular layout may vary, but for example, this finds all of the ones that intersect with the `rect`, calling `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` for each of those and appending them to the array.
2. Your `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` is specifying that all of the cells should have their center at 100, 100 within the collection view, and have a size of 10, 10. I.e. in short, you're specifying that they all be at the exact same position, overlapping with each other. That's a little curious. Usually you'd have each cell with some unique `center`.

   If you want them in a 50 x 50 grid, you might do:

   ```
   //  CustomLayout.m

   #import "CustomLayout.h"

   static const CGSize    kCellSize    = { 70, 30 };  // make whatever size you want
   static const CGFloat   kCellSpacing = 5;
   static const NSInteger kCellsPerRow = 50;

   @implementation CustomLayout

   - (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds{
       return true;
   }

   - (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize {
       NSInteger count = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];
       if (count == 0) return CGSizeZero;

       NSInteger numberOfColumns = MIN(kCellsPerRow, count);
       NSInteger numberOfRows = (count - 1) % kCellsPerRow + 1;
       return CGSizeMake(numberOfColumns * (kCellSize.width + kCellSpacing) + kCellSpacing,
                         numberOfRows * (kCellSize.height + kCellSpacing) + kCellSpacing);
   }

   - (NSArray<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
       NSMutableArray <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *attributes = [NSMutableArray array];

       NSInteger count = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];
       NSInteger numberOfRows = (count - 1) % kCellsPerRow + 1;

       NSInteger startColumn = MAX(0, floorf(rect.origin.x / (kCellSize.width + kCellSpacing)));
       NSInteger endColumn = MIN(kCellsPerRow, ceilf((rect.origin.x + rect.size.width) / (kCellSize.width + kCellSpacing)));

       NSInteger startRow = MAX(0, floorf(rect.origin.y / (kCellSize.height + kCellSpacing)));
       NSInteger endRow = MIN(numberOfRows, ceilf((rect.origin.y + rect.size.height) / (kCellSize.height + kCellSpacing)));

       for (NSInteger row = startRow; row < endRow; row++) {
           for (NSInteger column = startColumn; column < endColumn; column++) {
               NSInteger index = row * kCellsPerRow + column;
               if (index < count) {
                   [attributes addObject:[self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0]]];
               }
           }
       }

       return attributes;
   }

   - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];

       NSInteger column = indexPath.item % kCellsPerRow;
       NSInteger row = indexPath.item / kCellsPerRow;

       attributes.size = kCellSize;
       attributes.center = CGPointMake(column * (kCellSize.width  + kCellSpacing) + kCellSpacing + kCellSize.width / 2,
                                       row    * (kCellSize.height + kCellSpacing) + kCellSpacing + kCellSize.height / 2);

       return attributes;
   }

   @end
   ```

   Obviously, if you want a 50 x 50 grid, then you presumably want the number of cells to be 2,500, not 40.
3. I'm sure it was omitted for the sake of brevity, but your code snippet does not demonstrate the setting of the collection view's `collectionViewLayout`.

Anyway, the above rendered the following collection view:

[image]

Now, I made my cells large enough so I could put a label in there and show the cell's `indexPath.item`, but make it whatever size you want.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have tried doing it like your above method before but in my `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` the returned attribute is null. From the documentation it says it will return nil if there is no item at the indexpath. I updated my question with the desired layout. thanks

Comment: @Peter - See example 50x50 grid collection view.